# Creating and Deploying Windows 8 Pro images for Surface Pro tablets

Tags: windows-8, disk-image, microsoft-surface, disk-cloning

I have a stack of Microsoft Surface Pro tablets that I would like to setup with a base image, and some software for the company I work for. I know on Desktop machines I can go into Audit mode, make changes, then SYSPREP and clone the drives to all the new systems, but what would be the process on Windows 8 Pro tablets?

Comment: Exactly the same process.  Surface Pro devices are just like any other Windows x86-64 device.

Comment: @Ramhound So I can use a netbook to deploy the image? Or do I need to plug in to each one?

Comment: You can deploy the image however you NORMALLy do it the Surface Pro has no limitations in that regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2013/05/16/pxe-deployment-with-surface-pro.aspx

Summary:

1. Update firmware to at least May 2013 revision to get PXE boot support
2. Plug in the Surface Pro USB Ethernet Adapter (note: it is unlikely that any ethernet adapter other than the Microsoft one will work, because the boot firmware probably only supports Microsoft's own USB ethernet adapter) and connect it to a network with a WDS server
3. Press and hold the volume down button and then press the power button, continue to hold the volume down button until the Surface starts to boot from the USB key.
4. A dialog box will appear that states that it is “Checking Media Presence……”. Then it will “Start PXE over IPv4”.
5. When prompted press Enter for network boot service.

From here the instructions are identical to doing a PXE install of Windows on any other Windows desktop/laptop device

Answer (score 3):

Use the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2012 and use USB Media, it might be faster and cheaper than using the Ethernet adaptor. USBs are cheap. As long as your image is fresh, they won't need to get updates, but joining to the domain could be tricky...

Building images for 8 is no different than images for 7.

1. Install MDT 2012 & ADK 8.0
2. Build Two Shares, one for building images, and another for deployment.
3. Build your reference image using an MDT task sequence and a VM. (Keep drivers out of your image
4. PXE is great and all, but USB may be easier, and works just as well. Export your deployment media to USB in the MDT 2012 workbench.
5. Deploy the images using a the second deployment share and push all the drivers, apps, and updates during the task sequence.

This way you don't have to worry about PXE, NIC drivers, server setup, WDS, or anything, boot to USB and away you go. The MDT Media export will create a ISO you need to convert to USB.

[image: Export Media in MDT 2012]

Export Media to USB w/ MDT 2012 Update 1 and boot to USB. Its that easy.

Comment: You know, obviously you know your stuff about MDT... Do you got a quick list of all the applications I need for standard Microsoft tools?

Comment: @Luke, I'm assuming you mean WDS, ADK, MDT?

Comment: Yup. I would like a full list, then I can look up details

Comment: Really all you need is MDT 2012 and ADK 8.0 WDS is really optional. Unless you have a copy of Server 2008 or 2012, its not worth messing with. Check out my blog if you really wanna know more.